# Synchronization between SQL Server and SQL Server Express databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a requirement where the client database changes should be sync with the server (centralized). All clients use only SQL Server Express where as the server is of SQL Server 2008 R2. Do we have any way to do this without Microsoft Sync framework? With sync framework, all data starts from the beginning which is taking longer time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what acceptable latency is, what the network latency/reliability is, whether clients are connected/disconnected, and whether or not changes made at the clients need to be sent back to the server, assuming you want to send incremental changes, you have options database and log backup/restore, transactional replication and merge replication.  There may be more, but those are the more common solutions that will synchronize two servers.

If you are looking for bi-directional data flow, then [merge replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx) is the appropriate solution.

> Merge replication is typically used in server-to-client environments. Merge replication is appropriate in any of the following situations:
>
> - Multiple Subscribers might update the same data at various times and propagate those changes to the Publisher and to other Subscribers.
> - Subscribers need to receive data, make changes offline, and later synchronize changes with the Publisher and other Subscribers.
> - Each Subscriber requires a different partition of data.
> - Conflicts might occur and, when they do, you need the ability to detect and resolve them.
> - The application requires net data change rather than access to intermediate data states. For example, if a row changes five times at a Subscriber before it synchronizes with a Publisher, the row will change only once at the Publisher to reflect the net data change (that is, the fifth value).

Comment: Yes.. Incremental changes should be sent. If there is any change in schema at cleint side that should also to be sent server. Replication is not possible with SQL Express version. Am I correct?

Comment: Note: We need bi-derectional synchronization, i.e. changes in server/client should reflect in other.

Comment: Use merge replication then.  I've updated my response above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Greg, it is really helpful.. I am trying the merge replication, meanwhile can you please confirm that merge replication will handle schema changes too?  Also do we have data filtering option with this replication? I mean when publisher sync info to subscriber can we filter data based on a column?

Comment: The answer to your questions is yes, you can read about it in the link i provided above.